# Android keystore password field

Tags: android, passwords, keystore

I have finished developing an android application and decided to signed it with a keystore.
I have no problem for this process, but I do have a question regarding the keystore's password. I'm creating the keystore from eclipse, at `Keystore selection` window, i chosed to `create new keystore`. After i pressed next, under the `Key Creation` window, im required to key in details for the keystore ; alias, validity, password etc.

What i wanted to ask is, is there any difference between the password field in the `Key Creation` windows and the `Keystore selection` windows? I tried putting in same passwords for both and it works fine for me. Can i chose to put in different password? Does it affect anything for that particular keystore? Hopefully anyone could provide me an insight for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keystores hold **many** keys. Whereas your key is a single item **contained** in the keystore. They *can* have the same password, but that compromises your keystore if your key's password is leaked somehow. I would recommend having the keystore and key password differ.

So yes, the password fields are for two separate things because you are creating two separate items, and following good password practices, they should each have two separate passwords.

Comment: Correect me if i'm wrong, does that mean that the .keystore file password is only for access towards they keys inside it, while the password for the key is the 1 used to sign the application?

Comment: You're correct. Keystore password opens access to all the keys inside (which are still locked),and the key password opens just that key.