# Android signing key - multiple keys in your keystore?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio to create a new signing key for my application. In the creation wizard, we are prompted for a key store password, and then a separate Key password.

This post explains the difference between the two pretty well:

[Android keystore password field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035636/android-keystore-password-field)

So two parts to the question:

1. Why would you want to put multiple keys into a single key store, practically, for android development? My thinking is that if I were to create more applications, I would create a new keystore for each.
2. In this case, using the same password for both keystore and key is fine? Is that right?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To contradict the previous respondent:

1) Normally you would want only one private key for all your apps. A private key is a reference to an author, not an application. You don't need a new private key, or a new keystore for each app in a normal course of action.

2) Your link pretty much answers your question: it's a good practice to have all your passwords different, the decision of following or not following it is up to you.

And the [official link](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#considerations) to support my ideas.

Comment: Ok, if a private key is a reference to an author, when would you put multiple keys in a keystore? I can't think of a scenario. Maybe something like an organization has a keystore, and employees each have a signing key for their branch of apps. Employees keep all the keys in that one keystore?

Comment: @user3203425 Frankly, I can hardly imagine this situation. From the link you can see that signing apps with the same key facilitates communication between them, why would you want to artificially give up this?

Comment: ok fair enough, can you think of a case (relevant to android development) when you'd want to have multiple keys in one of these keystores?

Comment: @user3203425 it took time to write this comment and I need to conclude I don't possess the needed depth of knowledge of app signing to competently give you such example. I don't see any difference between placing your different keys into one keystore all together or each in a separate keystore. I guess you question was actually about that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the keystore holds many keys that are used for publishing multiple apps. One circumstance where you would have a multiple keys in a keystore is if you want to provide different flavours of your app (e.g. Free version, Paid version, etc...).

With regards to your second question, you can have the same password for them but that would be a security risk since you could have a key compromised affecting all the other keys on your keystore.

Comment: Are there any advantages though to keeping all your keys in one keystore? Even if in the app flavors scenario? I'd prefer to have a separate keystore for each that can be silo'd in my organization.